# Spring Batch: How do I use decider based on my Reader result?

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. I found out that by use of `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`, I can set up key value pairs and get them in future steps.

```
<step id="step1">....</step>
<decision id="decision1">.... />
```

When I used `Tasklet` instead of reader, I did following:

1. Created bean of `ExecutionContextPromotionListener` with expected keys in my batch config file.
2. Registered the `Listener` to my step.
3. Put the key-value pairs in `executionContext` retrieved from `chunkContext` inside my `Tasklet` like below:
4. Now the `Decider` can read from the step execution context as follows and decide.

But, I want to take decision based on Reader from previous step. So, in my decision, how to get the value from Reader? Or is my approach wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: What do you want the reader to provide that will be used by the next state's decider?

Comment: Say, read something from a database.
if found -> pass this to next step and read something else based upon that
else -> exit.
Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

simple way is you can make use of Execution context from your step and can pass on the values into the next step .

So, in you first step do something like this

```
// ...
ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
stepContext.put("DATA_KEY", dataToShare );
```

then in your next step you can read this using the execution context.

```
ExecutionContext jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
dataToShare = jobContext.get("DATA_KEY");
```

you just need to manage the keys  - the key that you use to put in first step and read it in next step